# Regarding the new requirements for updated Android apps in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-sdk-tools

Google Play recently issued a heads up to Android developers to update their apps with three new changes : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html

I have a question regarding updating the targeted SDK to version 26. When I made this change for one of my apps, the Developer console showed me a warning saying that this new APK would not support an x number of devices, since it does not fall into some SDK version criteria. Since the app did not have too many active installs, I went ahead with it.

Now I need to do this for another app of mine which has quite a good number of active users. Would making this change of targeted SDK version have any impact on user having low end Android OS or older device models?

Could somebody please explain what might be the problems one might face while making such a change, from perspective of existing and new users?

Would love some clarification from anyone who has some info, but particularly from android app developers who have already made these changes.

Answer (score 2):

From a user perspective: no problems, because changing the target SDK does not mean changing the minSDK.

For you as a developer: depending on the gap between current and future target SDK, there may be quite a lot of work to do because the runtime will handle things differently under the hood depending on the target SDK (e.g. permission handling, use of certain libraries, rendering of UI components).

Quoting from documentation for [<uses-sdk>](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target)

> As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app continues to work the way you expect. You can disable such compatibility behaviors by specifying targetSdkVersion to match the API level of the platform on which it's running. For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher and also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens (because support for API level 11 implicitly supports larger screens).
>   There are many compatibility behaviors that the system may enable based on the value you set for this attribute. Several of these behaviors are described by the corresponding platform versions in the [Build.VERSION_CODES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) reference.